# Can't open my app from facebook in-app browser iOS 9

Tags: facebook, ios9, applinks

I've posted some article at facebook that links my app.
When I clicked link at the facebook in-app browser,
I excepted launch my app, but go to app store. Altough my app is installed.
I tried some meta tags like these:

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="testApp://" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="123456" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="testApp" />
<meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />
```

and

```
if (/Android|iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        window.location = app;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.location = mobileFallback;
        }, 25);
    } else {
        window.location = desktopFallback;
    }
```

I can't figure out at all..
This issue only appeared in iOS 9.x AFAIK.
The app link works well iOS under 9 and safari.

I found some app that works well in facebook in-app browser(i.e whatsapp).

Is this native app problem? or client-side problem?

What am I missing?

Any opinion would be appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: I would try this further more and if you are able to identify more examples where this is working (e.g. spotify ... etc) then I would report a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) with repro steps and screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

There is an active bug report open for this https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/802238099898150/

---

As far as I understand, iOS 9 changed the way apps can interact with other Apps using custom URL schemes (Read more [here](http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes)). The basic idea is that Facebook can no longer intelligently open other apps using a custom scheme as they have to register all the schemes they support inside the App plist.

I have tested AppLinks with YouTube, 9GAG, Flipboard and IMdB and none of them work as they used to. The advertised behaviour (found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios)) is that your App will be opened if your link contains the relevant html app links tags.

Now the only way to open your app is to tap "Share" in the Facebook browser of the page you want to open, and you should see a "Open in 9GAG" line item that will open your app.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to contact my company's ios dev.